# Best practices: services calling to other services or directly the repositories?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-management

Let's say I have entities A and B. For each one I have serviceX and repositoryX. If, from serviceA, I need something from B: shouldn't I be calling serviceB? or should I directly call repositoryB?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "directly call" mean? How are your repositories and services even accessible without using the entities? Do you plan on introducing them via singletons, service providers or the like? We need some more details, I guess

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was generically. I thought it would be understood there's a repositoryA with some operations over entity A and a serviceA to manage A's business logic. Same for B. They're singletons, yeah. The question is about best practices. Is it ok that for a method in serviceA to user repositoryB.foo() or should it be calling a method serviceB.foo() that calls repositoryB.foo()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand you have in case A and B two layers: business logic (service) and data access (repository). 
The best practice is to see the A and B as separate components which communicate via interfaces. 
The data access for A should be private for the component A. So if the component B needs some data from component A, it should ask component A using its public interface, not its data access layer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's actually the way I'm doing it. It's just I'm getting some circular references but I can't see a way to avoid them. I'll post a new question.